# Latching Relay with no power supply

Tags: latching-relay

I've been searching for a latching relay which will remain closed without the application of external power.

One side is a generator with remote start - closed=turn on, open=turn off, voltage around 5vDC, other side is pressure switch. So when the pressure switch reaches its level, the circuit needs to close, and stay closed even when pressure goes back down.

I'd prefer if it just closes once and has to be manually reset.
If need be, I have a 120V outlet nearby, but it's easier not to use it.

I'm not a pro so I haven't had any luck with search terms.

Comment: This site is not a design service for you. Instead if you can show the design you are working with and have some specific problem or questions about it then folks here can offer support in the way of answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is not a design service.

Comment: Errrm.  Design?  It's a question about what kind of relay does the described task.

Comment: `I've been searching for a latching relay` .... apparently you have not searched for `latching relay`   .... you do  not need to be a pro to search for the obvious

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong with search terms such as "mechanical latching relays" such as [this one](https://www.functionaldevices.com/products/lighting-controls/latching-relays/) or "magnetic latching relays"?

These normally have two separate coils to which you apply a current to latch or unlatch.